# Buscar todas las palabras de una línea de un fichero en otro archivo diccionario, terminal de linux

Tags: bash, unix, awk, grep, procesamiento-de-texto

Necesito un comando desde la terminal de linux para hacer lo siguiente:

tengo un archivo diccionario.txt con una palabra en una sola columna así:

```
amarillo
verde
azul
gato
perro
cielo
marrón
```

y un archivo bigramas.txt

```
negro azul
amarillo verde
perro gato
rojo marrón
gato azul
```

me gustaría que la salida fuera la siguiente:

```
amarillo verde
perro gato
gato azul
```

Agradecería una solución que no implique el comando grep, siempre que lo uso con archivos grandes se corta de forma sorpresiva, el archivo diccionario.txt tiene poco mas de un millón de palabras y el archivo bigramas.txt tiene mas de doce millones de líneas.

He intentado:

```
grep -wf diccionario.txt bigramas.txt > salida.txt
```

pero solo me muestra una de las palabras de bigramas.txt y no las dos, como yo necesito, he probado grep con archivos pequeños pero no parece funcionar con archivos de millones de líneas.

La lógica del fichero final es encontrar todas las palabras que hay en una línea del archivo bigramas.txt en el archivo diccionario.txt y si encuentra todas las palabras guardar esa línea en un fichero salida.txt

Comment: Pero debe aparecer una sola o ambas palabras? Por el ejemplo entiendo que una

Comment: Se trata de buscar las dos palabras que aparecen en una línea del archivo bigramas.txt, en el diccionario.txt, en caso de que encuentre las dos palabras debe guardar esa línea en el archivo salida.txt

observa que en el resultado se encuentra la línea:
amarillo verde

porque ambas se encuentran en el archivo diccionario.txt

pero no
rojo marrón

porque rojo se encuentra en diccionario.txt y marrón no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

¡Awk al rescate!

```
awk 'FNR==NR {palabras[$0]; next} ($1 in palabras && $2 in palabras)' dicc bigramas
```

Utilizamos Awk para procesar dos ficheros de golpe: primero "dicc.txt" para ir acumulando las posibles palabras en un vector `palabras[]`. Después, procesa "bigramas.txt" validando si ambas palabras están en el vector. Si es así, la condición `($1 in palabras && $2 in palabras)` es cierta y Awk ejecuta su acción predeterminada: imprimir la línea.

El truco `FNR==NR {cosas a hacer cuando se lee el primer fichero}` se explica en que `NR` es el número de registro (línea en este caso) que se está leyendo y `FNR` el número de registro del fichero que se está leyendo actualmente. Por tanto, ambos solamente coincidirán cuando se esté leyendo el primer fichero.

Comment: Muchas gracias fedorqui por tu respuesta, funciona perfectamente.

Comment: Qué bien, @LuisMiguel. Si hubiera más palabras en cada línea o su número no fuera constante se podría hacer con un bucle, etc.